# Can TSOP1130 work also at 850mn?

Tags: photodiode, phototransistor, photosensor

In the sheet, they test it with a 940nm IR LED. There are no clear specifications for the wavelength (range) it works with.

But I have 850nm LEDs (powerful ones).
Will it work the same, or will it perceive a weaker signal?

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question:

> But I have 850nm LEDs (powerful ones). Will it work the same, or will it perceive a weaker signal?

The Vishay TSOP1130 is reported as obsolete, and can't find a datasheet for it on the Vishay site.

In the [datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/26554/VISHAY/TSOP1130.html) found on a different site there is *Figure 12.  Relative Spectral Sensitivity vs. Wavelength*:

[image]

So, with a 850 nm LED expect the TSOP1130 to perceive a weaker signal which is approx 30% of that compared to using the 950 nm wavelength used for the characterisation in the datashseet.